# Displaying form when session expire issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have created a web application using ext.net and c# in visual studio 2010. When the user click on the about button, the about window is displayed from the index page. In web.config file I have following code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" defaultUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2000"/>
</authentication>
```

My problem is that, when the session is expired and the user click on the about button, the login page is displayed inside the about window. I have to refresh the page manually to redirect to the login page. I don't want the login page display in the about window when session is expire. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to choose among some good answers from your previous asked question to let other encourage help you.

Comment: @PankajGarg I know that, but I have not receive the correct answer that could help me. If the answer could not help me then why should I accept the answer?

Comment: It's the matter of your 12 pending un-reviewed queries !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the below javascript in the login page head section

```
<script>
if(self!=top)
 top.location.href=window.location.href;
</script>
```

`self` means the current window, that will become the window inside the frame. `top` means the top most window. that is the browser window. So if `top!=self` means if the current window is not the topmost window

Comment: +1 got to learn something new. can you please explain what exactly is meant by self!=top ?